# Can I change the language in Bazaar Explorer?

Tags: bazaar

Bazaar Explorer mixes languages in its user interfaces. Part of it are in German, the other parts in English. That's why I'd like to set the language explicit to English. How can I set the language in Bazaar Explorer?

Bazaar Explorer is running on an English Windows, but with German locale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent versions of Bazaar Explorer you can change the language with Tools - Options - Appearance - User Interface - Language, or manually set `language` option in bazaar.conf.

Answer (score 2):

Question was answered on [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr-explorer/+question/102063). You can set the enviroment-variable LANG or LANGUAGE to 'en' in order to have the interface in English only.